# Issue with change comma to new line PHP

Tags: php, string, laravel, replace, laravel-blade

I have a problem with changing comma to new line in Laravel Blade,

I have code

```
{{ preg_replace("/,/", "\n", ($invoice->seller_address))}}
```

in this code I have Customer data separate with comma, for example

```
Customer X, Street 5, Code, City
```

and I need text

```
CustomerX
Street 5
Code
City
```

but it doesn't work. I get the result:

```
CustomerX Street 5 Code City
```

I tried `str_replace` too without success.

Comment: why don't you use explode() and then implode() with NEWLINE?

Comment: If you're outputting to HTML, you need to use `<br>` or put it in a `<pre>` block so that formatting is retained.

Comment: Unless you're putting this into a `textarea` or similar, you might want to use `{!! preg_replace("/,/", "<br/>", ($invoice->seller_address)) !!}`

Comment: `{!! preg_replace("/,/", "<br/>", ($invoice->seller_address)) !!}` working very well, thank you

Comment: If you use View Source you'll see that the newlines are there. The browser then reformats it like it normally does.

Comment: Why are you using preg_replace to replace one hardcode character? Why not use the far less could and memory hungry str_replace?

Comment: I change to `str_replace` and it working well too. Problem was in lack of {!! !!} instead of {{ }} but I have new problem now, Is it possible to change only first line to `bold` where I have Customer Name?